Paginated Report - PowerBINotAuthorizedException - Get report failed - 401 (POWER BI)
  async getEmbedToken(workspaceId, reportId) {
    const tokenEndpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
    const postData = {
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: clientSecret,
      scope: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default",
    };

    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(
      tokenEndpoint,
      qs.stringify(postData),
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      }
    );

    const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
    console.log("accessToken------------", accessToken);
    const datasetId = await _resourceSettings.getDatasetId(
      accessToken,
      workspaceId,
      reportId
    );
    const powerBiApiEndpoint = `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}/GenerateToken`;
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
    const body = {
      datasets: [{ id: datasetId }],
      accessLevel: "View", // Optional, defaults to View
    };
    const embedTokenResponse = await axios.post(powerBiApiEndpoint, body, {
      headers,
    });

    return { embedToken: embedTokenResponse.data.token, datasetId: datasetId };
  }

  async getDatasetId(accessToken, workspaceId, reportId) {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}/datasources`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );

    return response.data.value[0].datasourceId;
  }

I have created a workspace in power bi service and given permission for my service principal. when i create a paginated report using power bi report builder and published to power bi service it can be viewed in my workspace in my power bi service. when i try to embed the same in my react js application it will throw an error like this
{
    "message": "PowerBINotAuthorizedException",
    "detailedMessage": "Get report failed",
    "errorCode": "401",
    "level": 6,
    "technicalDetails": {
        "requestId": "320dea56-3278-4b5c-9ae8-ee42eced0666"
    }
}

i have created service principal in azure ad and given these app permissions
App.Read.All
Dataset.Read.All
Dataset.ReadWrite.All
Report.Read.All
Report.ReadWrite.All

please look in to this issue and help me to identify the problem
